# AMPscript round a number unless it's 'round'

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to format an outcome with FormatNumber.

FormatNumber(@regularprice, "N2") works fine and shows me my price with a decimal number. But I'm looking for an easy way to show @regularprice as a 'round' number unless it has a value after the full stop/dot. How can this be done?

So
if regularprice = 25.50 --> show me 25.50

but if
regular price = 25 --> show me 25 and not 25.00

What am i missing or is it not possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a usecase for the modulus function (`mod()`) - essentially you want to test if something is a whole number.

references:

https://ampscript.guide/mod/

https://exceljet.net/formula/number-is-whole-number

Example - See this snippet:

https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/HCsl49xb

or in full:

```
%%[
SET @myNumber = 25
/* change @myNumber to 25.5 to test */ 
SET @modulus  = mod(@myNumber, 1)

IF @modulus ==  0 THEN
 /* this is a whole number */
    SET @debug = "whole number"
ELSE
    /* this is not -  reformat */
    SET @debug = "not a whole number"
    SET @myNumber = FormatNumber(@myNumber, "N2")

ENDIF
]%% %%=v(@modulus)=%%; %%=v(@debug)=%%; %%=v(@myNumber)=%%
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would be the best solution, but you could "cut" the `.00` from the string in case it's there using the [Substring](https://ampscript.guide/substring/) function:

```
%%[

...

if indexOf(@regularprice, ".00") > 0 then
  set @price = Substring(@regularprice,1, Subtract(IndexOf(@regularprice,".00"),1))

else 

set @price = @regularprice

endif

]%%
```

Resources: https://ampscript.guide/substring/